# Handling "family=" and "given=" within the "author" field

Tags: bibliographies, citing, key-value, zotero

My zotero+BetterBibTeX has exported some citations like this

```latex
@article{abduMagneticDeclinationControl1981,
  title = {Magnetic Declination Control of the Equatorial {{F}} Region Dynamo Electric Field Development and Spread {{F}}},
  author = {family=Abdu, given=MA, given-i=MA and family=Bittencourt, given=JA, given-i=JA and family=Batista, given=IS, given-i=IS},
  date = {1981},
  journaltitle = {Journal of Geophysical Research: Space Physics},
  shortjournal = {Journal of Geophysical Research: Space Physics},
  volume = {86},
  number = {A13},
  pages = {11443--11446},
  publisher = {{Wiley Online Library}},
  issn = {0148-0227},
  keywords = {F-region scintillation's cause}
}
```

I've never seen the options "family=" or "given=" before. Even though, I tried to use it that way, and when I cited it, my LaTeX didn't not properly handle these fields. It results in
[image]

How to handle (or remove) it in order to get a sane citation?

Comment: that is syntax for biblatex so probably you have set somewhere an option that you use biblatex.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually I found the solution. In (using Zotero 6.0.22):

1. Edit
2. Preferences
3. Better BibTeX
4. Export
5. BibLaTeX -> Export -> BibLaTeX
6. Uncheck "Use BibLaTeX extended name name format (requires biblatex 3.5)"

[image]

It disables these weird fields in the citation options.

Comment: Which is exactly what Ulrike Fischer told you in a comment.

Comment: @cfr No. He told a guess. I told the answer.